# Python Script to convert a csv to yml to use in azure devops

Tags: python, azure-devops

We are creating a python script to convert a csv into yaml we going to use this yaml to create a pipeline from azure devops I have created below script :

```
import csv
import yaml
in_file  = open(r'C:\Users\246742\Desktop\Book2.csv', "r")
out_file = open('yaml_file.yaml', "w")
items = []

def convert_to_yaml(line, counter):
    item = {
        'task': line[0],
        'displayName': line[1],
        'inputs': {
            'ConnectedServiceName' : line[2],
            'Action' :line[3], 
            'KeyVaultName' :line[4],
            'SecretName' :line[5],
            'Secret':line[6],
            'VariableName':line[7],
            'Overwrite' : line[8]
            }
    }
    items.append(item)

try:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    next(reader) # skip headers
    for counter, line in enumerate(reader):
        convert_to_yaml(line, counter)
    out_file.write( yaml.dump(items, default_flow_style=False) )

finally:
    in_file.close()
    out_file.close()
```

which gives an output as :

```
- displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: SetSecret adf-bookings'
  inputs:
    Action: abc_QA_SPN
    ConnectedServiceName: abc_QA_SPN
    KeyVaultName: SetSecret
    Overwrite: adf-booking
    Secret: adf-booking
    SecretName: $(QAkvabc)
    VariableName: $(booking)
  task: maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-azurekeyvault.azurekeyvault.azurekeyvaultactions@2
- displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: SetSecret adf-booking'
  inputs:
    Action: abc_QA_SPN
    ConnectedServiceName: abc_QA_SPN
    KeyVaultName: SetSecret
    Overwrite: adf-booking
    Secret: adf-booking
    SecretName: $(QAkvabc)
    VariableName: $(booking)
  task: maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-azurekeyvault.azurekeyvault.azurekeyvaultactions@2
```

but the required output is :

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
- group: Devportal

pool:
  name: Ubuntu 20.04

steps:
- task: maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-azurekeyvault.azurekeyvault.azurekeyvaultactions@2
  displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: SetSecret adf-bookings'
  inputs:
    ConnectedServiceName: 'abc_QA_SPN'
    Action: SetSecret
    KeyVaultName: '$(QAkvabc)'
    SecretName: 'booking'
    Secret: '$(booking)'
    VariableName: 'booking'
    Overwrite: false
- task: maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-azurekeyvault.azurekeyvault.azurekeyvaultactions@2
  displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: SetSecret adf-bookings'
  inputs:
    ConnectedServiceName: 'abc_QA_SPN'
    Action: SetSecret
    KeyVaultName: '$(QAkvabc)'
    SecretName: 'booking'
    Secret: '$(booking)'
    VariableName: 'booking'
    Overwrite: false
```

here the order of the dictionary changes according to the alphabets and not able to get quotes in values

The csv is as below :
[image]

could some one help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use a template processor like `jinja2`.

Create the following template file:

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
- group: Devportal

pool:
  name: Ubuntu 20.04

steps:
{%- for task in tasks %}
- task: {{ task["name"] }}
  displayName: '{{ task["displayName"] }}'
  inputs:
    ConnectedServiceName: '{{ task["inputs"] }}'
    Action: {{ task["Action"] }}
    KeyVaultName: '{{ task["KeyVaultName"] }}'
    SecretName: '{{ task["SecretName"] }}'
    Secret: '{{ task["Secret"] }}'
    VariableName: '{{ task["VariableName"] }}'
    Overwrite: {{ task['Overwrite']|lower }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then process `Book2.csv` as tasks:

```
# pip install jinja2
from jinja2 import Template
from csv import DictReader

with (open('template.yaml.j2') as tplfile,
      open('Book2.csv') as csvfile,
      open('config.yaml', 'w') as yamlfile):
    template = Template(tplfile.read())
    reader = DictReader(csvfile)
    data = template.render(tasks=reader)
    yamlfile.write(data)
```

Output:

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
- group: Devportal

pool:
  name: Ubuntu 20.04

steps:
- task: 
  displayName: 'My first task'
  inputs:
    ConnectedServiceName: 'abc_QA_SPN'
    Action: SetSecret
    KeyVaultName: '$(QAkvabc)'
    SecretName: 'booking'
    Secret: '$(bookingst)'
    VariableName: 'booking'
    Overwrite: false

- task: 
  displayName: 'My second task"
  inputs:
    ConnectedServiceName: 'abc_QA_SPN'
    Action: SetSecret
    KeyVaultName: '$(QAkvabc)'
    SecretName: 'booking'
    Secret: '$(bookingst)'
    VariableName: 'booking'
    Overwrite: false
```

Comment: You should use `Jinja` as template processor. Create a yaml template then populate with a dict.